# Subtracting two-dimensional php array elements from eachother and outputting to the same table

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array filled with the 12 month names and average temperatures from 2 different years. As of right now, I have them printing into an html table just fine while using a foreach loop. However, I also need to find a way to calculate the difference and print it into the same table next to the rest of the data, as well as print the total difference altogether. I also need to make the difference print as red text if the difference is higher than 2, and green if it is lower than -2. Otherwise the color doesn't change. Because this is pretty much the first time I've ever used php at an extent, I'm totally at a loss about how to implement this.

This is my code so far, which successfully prints into an html table:

```
<?php
        $months = array
          (
          array("Jan",33.6,32.6),
          array("Feb",35.6,42.9),
          array("Mar",43.1,40.3),
          array("Apr",53.2,51.4),
          array("May",62.7,68.1),
          array("Jun",76.3,72.5),
          array("Jul",76.3,77.1),
          array("Aug",74.6,78.6),
          array("Sep",68,73.2),
          array("Oct",57,60.1),
          array("Nov",46.7,45.3),
          array("Dec",37.7,41.0)
          );
          
        //print array into an html table
        
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr><th>Month</th><th>1950 - 2018</th><th>2018</th><th>Difference</th></tr>';
        foreach ($months as $month) {
            
            echo '<tr>';
            
            foreach ($month as $avg) {
                    echo '<td>' . $avg . '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
?>
```

and the expected result it something
 [similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgO3j.png)

Any advice would be very appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You have to calculate the difference between 2 dates and assign colors accordingly below your inner loop. Conditions look as follows:

```
$diff = $month[2] - $month[1];
$total += $diff;


if($diff < -2.0){
    echo '<td style="color:green">' . $diff . '</td>';
}else if($diff > 2.0){
    echo '<td style="color:red">' . $diff . '</td>';
}else{
    echo '<td>' . $diff . '</td>';
}
```

**Full Code:**

```
<?php

$months = array
  (
  array("Jan",33.6,32.6),
  array("Feb",35.6,42.9),
  array("Mar",43.1,40.3),
  array("Apr",53.2,51.4),
  array("May",62.7,68.1),
  array("Jun",76.3,72.5),
  array("Jul",76.3,77.1),
  array("Aug",74.6,78.6),
  array("Sep",68,73.2),
  array("Oct",57,60.1),
  array("Nov",46.7,45.3),
  array("Dec",37.7,41.0)
  );

echo '<table border = "1">';
echo '<tr><th>Month</th><th>1950 - 2018</th><th>2018</th><th>Difference</th></tr>';
$total = 0;

foreach ($months as $month) {
    echo '<tr>';

    foreach ($month as $avg) {
        echo '<td>' . $avg . '</td>';
    }

    $diff = $month[2] - $month[1];
    $total += $diff;


    if($diff < -2.0){
        echo '<td style="color:green">' . $diff . '</td>';
    }else if($diff > 2.0){
        echo '<td style="color:red">' . $diff . '</td>';
    }else{
        echo '<td>' . $diff . '</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}

echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>Total difference : $total</td></tr>";
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Oh, that worked perfectly! Thank you so much, this actually helps me understand a lot more!

Comment: @Kaijudile Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_walk` to add the temp diff to each subarray:

```
array_walk($months, function(&$month){
    $month[3] = $month[2] - $month[1]; 
});
```

Then $month[3] will be your difference.
I would remove the inner loop and explicitly echo the row per month for human readability:

```
foreach ($months as $month) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $month[0] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $month[1] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $month[2] . '</td>';
    echo '<td';

    if ($month[3] > 2) {
        echo ' style="color: red;"';
    }
    elseif ($month[3] < -2) {
        echo ' style="color: green;"';
    }

    echo '>' . $month[3] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: I was messing with this a little bit, and they still print perfectly to the table, but the array_walk doesn't seem to initialize $month[3] at all. Is there anything I can do to make that work properly?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I left out an ampersand to pass the month element into the anonymous function by reference.